# Python Pandas Get data from Source (single column) to Correct Tabular format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some txt files with data stored as a single column (see example below),I wish to read these files and create a pandas dataframe for each:

```
Header1
Header2
Header3
1
2
3
4
5
AValue1
AValue2
AValue3
AValue4
AValue5
BValue1
BValue2
BValue3
BValue4
BValue5
```

It is supposed to be data from a table and should look like this:

```
Header1   Header2   Header3
1         AValue1   BValue1
2         AValue2   BValue2
3         AValue3   BValue3
4         AValue4   BValue4
5         AValue5   BValue5
```

> Regarding the Data:  (1) The number of Headers and the number of rows
> can differ across the files but will always be known (so I can
> probably pass them as a parameter to some function). (2) Also there
> wont be any missing values. (3) The actual values for Headers and
> Column Values will of course be different for each file.

What is the best way to do this in Python/Pandas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- split string into a **list**
- take *headers* rows as column names
- reshape remaining data

```
import io


def long_data(data, headers=3):
    lines = data.split("\n")
    return pd.DataFrame(
        columns=lines[0:headers],
        data=np.array(lines[headers:])
        .reshape(headers, len(lines[headers:]) // headers)
        .T,
    )


df = long_data(
    """Header1
Header2
Header3
1
2
3
4
5
AValue1
AValue2
AValue3
AValue4
AValue5
BValue1
BValue2
BValue3
BValue4
BValue5"""
)
```

|  | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | AValue1 | BValue1 |
| 1 | 2 | AValue2 | BValue2 |
| 2 | 3 | AValue3 | BValue3 |
| 3 | 4 | AValue4 | BValue4 |
| 4 | 5 | AValue5 | BValue5 |